# What is the name of the region between parentheses after the class name in Python?

Tags: python

For a function definition you'd speak of the "arguments" or "signature" of the function but is there a similar name for the list of parent classes and keyword arguments (since `__init_subclass__`) that can be used for classes? How could I refer to this when writing documentation?

```py
# Parameters, arguments, function signature
#       v----------v
def func(arg1, arg2):
  pass

# Similarly, what's this called?
#        v-----------------------------v
class Cls(Parent, Mixin, mixin_arg=True):
  pass
```

Comment: I'd refer to it as the argument list, per the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html): `classdef: 'class' NAME ['(' [arglist] ')'] ':' suite`

Comment: Very nice find! If you write it up I'll accept it as an answer in a bit, barring interesting new community oriented answers :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe one issue is the arguments list of a class would usually be understood by the reader as that of the `__new__`/`__init__`. And a second issue is the argslist of the class definition statement goes into at least 3 different places (`metaclass` does into the internal machinery, the bases go to the metaclass, and the kwargs go to `__init_subclass__`). OTOH the official documentation does use "keyword arguments that are specified in the class definition" ([when it covers the metaclass hint](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init_subclass__#metaclasses))

Comment: That first part could be avoided by either specifying "the class definition's argument list" or with example code that does not contain `__new__` or `__init__` functions. And with your second point you mean that by simply saying "class argument list" not everyone would think of the metaclass and keywords aswell?

Answer (score 2):

From my Python manual's specification for a class definition, perhaps we should call it the *inheritance argument list*:

[image]

Comment: It's a nice answer! I do feel like this excludes the metaclass hint and keyword arguments as they are not there to specify inheritance. It also seems that this source looks like the grammar from jonrsharpe's comment except that it it's not an official documentation (is it?). Are there reasons to prefer this source over the official documentation?

Comment: This is indeed from my Python 3.6.4 windows `.chm` file downloaded with a standard Pyhon installation from python.org.

Comment: Any takes on the inclusion of the metaclass and kwargs?

Comment: I looked at [PEP 3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) and I can't really come up with anything other than *metaclass specification*. Not very exciting.

Comment: Actually it says "the parameter list passed to a class definition"! This means `argument list` or `parameter list` are good names for it

Comment: True, but that seems so vague. But I suppose that's on purpose so it can be open-ended for the future.